# in template namespace prefix is undeclared xsl 1.0

Tags: templates, xslt, namespaces

After so much reading I still feel so new to xsl. I have an xsl file that I am adding a template to (which I got off a web page that seems to work) - until I specify an output string with a namespace.
So my xsl file looks like this (with the stuff in the middle excluded for brevity:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:max="http://www.ibm.com/maximo" exclude-result-prefixes="max">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:variable name="pChunkSize" select="150" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="max:InvokeFMSPO"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="max:InvokeFMSPO">
        <xsl:text>
        </xsl:text>
        <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:fms="http://www.MitchellHumphrey.com/FMSServices">
            <soapenv:Header/>
            <soapenv:Body>
                <fms:CreatePOBatch>
                :
                :
                :
                                </fms:LineItems>

<fms:ExtendedDesc>
<fms:POBatchExtendedDesc>
                                    <xsl:apply-templates select="max:DESCRIPTION_LONGDESCRIPTION"/>

   </fms:POBatchExtendedDesc>
</fms:ExtendedDesc>
                            </fms:POBatchDocument>
</xsl:for-each>
                        </fms:Documents>
                    </fms:BatchInput>
                </fms:CreatePOBatch> 
            </soapenv:Body>
        </soapenv:Envelope>
    </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/max:InvokeFMSPO/max:FMSPOSet/max:PO/max:DESCRIPTION_LONGDESCRIPTION/text()" name="chunk">
<xsl:param name="pText" select="."/>

<xsl:if test="string-length($pText) >0">
<Type>HT</Type>
<fms:Text>
<xsl:value-of select=
   "substring($pText, 1, $pChunkSize)"/>
</fms:Text>
<xsl:call-template name="chunk">
<xsl:with-param name="pText"
    select="substring($pText, $pChunkSize+1)"/>
</xsl:call-template>
</xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Now in the template at the end (named chunk) I want to output some literal elements to be included in the output so I tried this:

```
<fms:Text>
<xsl:value-of select=
   "substring($pText, 1, $pChunkSize)"/>
</fms:Text>
```

but I get an error:
"For element , namespace prefix 'fms' is undeclared."

if I take the "fms:" out it compiles and runs (but output is incorrect because the "fms:" is missing in the output) :

```
<Text>
<xsl:value-of select=
   "substring($pText, 1, $pChunkSize)"/>
</Text>
```

In the section above the last template declaration the "fms:" isn't a problem - why is it a problem in the last template and how do I get the "fms:" in my output?

as an aside its supposed to chunk a long text element in the input to a set of 150 length max element values over and over until the entire original string is represented in the output like this:

```
              <fms:ExtendedDesc>
                 <fms:POBatchExtendedDesc>
                    <fms:Type>HT</Type>
                    <fms:Text>150 chars max</Text>
                    <fms:Type>HT</Type>
                    <fms:Text>150 chars max</Text>
                    <fms:Type>HT</Type>
                    <fms:Text>the last few characters <= 150</Text>
                 </fms:POBatchExtendedDesc>
              </fms:ExtendedDesc>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use a prefix without binding it to a namespace.

Your stylesheet does have a namespace declaration for the `fms` prefix here:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:fms="http://www.MitchellHumphrey.com/FMSServices">
```

However, the **scope** of this declaration is limited to its parent `soapenv:Envelope` element and it descendants. You are trying to use the same prefix in another context, and that's why you get the error you report.

The solution is to move the declaration higher up in the hierarchy, so that it becomes in-scope for both templates that want to use it. IOW, move it to the `xsl:stylesheet` element's start-tag, where you already have the declarations for the `xsl` and `max` prefixes.

Comment: well i think i understand but that first declaration is just part of what i need in the output (that ends up in the output foc)- so if i move it higher it wont be literally in my output snymore eill it?

Comment: Of course it will. The XSLT processor will not output an ill-formed XML document. Try it and see.